# Does NPOI support Pivot charts?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, npoi

I am trying to create spreadsheet from template. Template is having 3 sheets:

- 1st one is chart sheet which contains pivot chart.
- 2nd sheet    contains pivot table which is used as data table for
  pivot chart in    1st sheet.
- 3rd sheet contains data table which is used as source for    pivot
  table in 2nd sheet.

When I fill data in 3rd sheet, pivot table generates correctly. However 1st sheet is doesn't appear in created excel document. Also when I open document it opens in recovery mode. It gives alert with following lines:

```
_Removed Part: /xl/pivotTables/pivotTable1.xml part. (PivotTable view) 
Repaired Part: /xl/workbook.xml part with XML error. (Workbook) Load error. Line 1, column 1035. 
Repaired Part: /xl/chartsheets/sheet1.xml part with XML error. (Chart sheet) Catastrophic failure Line 1, column 224._
```

When I put only pivot table and data table in template then document is created with no issue. 
Does NPOI has support for pivot charts? If not, can we do it using MS interop?